# Btc unconfirmed in recievers block chain wallet from last 9 days

Tags: transactions, blockchain

[image]

I sent btc to the address on 27 th august 1PnNad5w5LDFuUudVMnrb7tAVP4U7jUHyr

But in his blockchain wallet it showing  still pending. 
What to do now.suggest me please

txid cca36806a1fbad4738a15be7a0a3528af278501350d873f6f4577cd5d789322e